# Svelte Store Variable is Null on Page Load

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, sveltekit, svelte-store

I'm newish to Svelte and web development and am running into a problem juggling awaits. To start, I setup a store to get the auth of the current session and named it as currentUser. I then use the UID from currrentUser to retrieve some data from a Firestore. My issue is that upon loading the page the initial value of currentUser is null which breaks the onSnapshot function.

I currently use this async function to get the data:

```
async function getData() {
    let querySnapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', $currentUser.uid));
    profile = querySnapshot.data();
    return profile;
}
```

This works but its not reactive as it only runs once.

I would like to use the following function instead:

```
    $: profile = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', $currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
        console.log('Current data: ', doc.data());
        profile = doc.data();
    });
```

This function only works if the $currentUser.uid exists when it runs which on page load $currentUser.uid = null. However, once the store updates its able to console log the correct config but the page breaks and doesn't re-render.

Is there a way to wait for $currentUser.uid before running the onSnapshot function?

I have tried using something like this:

```
$: if ($currentUser.uid) {
  profile = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', $currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
      console.log('Current data: ', doc.data());
      resolve(doc.data());
    });
    // Make sure to unsubscribe when the component unmounts
    onUnmounted(unsubscribe);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While something like

```
<script>
    import {currentUser} from '...'
    import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'

    let profile
    let unsubscribe

    $: if ($currentUser.uid) {
        unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', $currentUser.uid), setProfile);
    }
    
    function setProfile(doc) {
        console.log('Current data: ', doc.data())
        profile = doc.data()
    }
    
    onDestroy(() => {
        if(unsubscribe) unsubscribe()
    })

</script>

{#if profile}
    {profile.username}
    ...
{/if}
```

might work, an alternative would be to export the uid as a prop and only mount the component in case the user is logged in (in case not he probably should be redirected somewhere else anyway..?)

```
{#if $currentUser}
  <Profile uid={$currentUser.uid} />
{/if}
```

###### Profile.svelte

```
<script>
    import {onDestroy} from 'svelte'

    export let uid
    let profile
    
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', uid), setProfile);
    
    function setProfile(doc) {
        console.log('Current data: ', doc.data())
        profile = doc.data()
    }
    
    onDestroy(unsubscribe)

</script>

{#if profile}
    {profile.username}
    ...
{/if}
```